# Read Data Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to recover data in my firebase database but it does not work.

```
void _userData() async {
    DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc("axelduf2006@gmail.com");
    documentReference.get().then((datasnapshot) {
      data = datasnapshot.data;
      return print("pseudo: ${data['pseudo']}");
    });
  }
```

my log console

[image]

I would like to know the value contained in pseudo in my database.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content (such as log console output). Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `datasnapshot.data` is a method, so `data = datasnapshot.data()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `data` with `data()` to get the `Map<String, dynamic>` of your document.

```
void _userData() async {
DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .doc("axelduf2006@gmail.com");
documentReference.get().then((datasnapshot) {
  data = datasnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // set it like this
  return print("pseudo: ${data['pseudo']}");
});
}
```

Passing the `data` will pass the definition of `Map<String, dynamic> Function`  ( `() => Map<String, dynamic>` ), not the actual `Map<String, dynamic>` of the document data.